# web form does not add or delete from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, webforms, smarty

I'm working on a basic web form (using PHP and smarty templates) that allows users to add and delete data from a mysql database table.  The data and form display fine, but nothing happens when a user tries to add or delete records from the table(not even the "cannot delete/add record' error message displays). Here is what the code looks like:

```
<?php //smartytest.php

$path =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require "$path/Smarty/Smarty.class.php";

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = "$path/temp/smarty/templates";
$smarty->compile_dir= "$path/temp/smarty/templates_c";
$smarty->cache_dir="$path/temp/smarty/cache";
$smarty->config_dir="$path/temp/smarty/configs";

require_once ("$path/phptest/login.php");

$db_server=mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if(!$db_server) die('unable to connect to MySQL: '. mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['author'])&&
    isset($_POST['title'])&&
    isset($_POST['category'])&&
    isset($_POST['year'])&&
    isset($_POST['isbn']))
    {
        $author = get_post('author');
        $title = get_post('title');
        $category=get_post('category');
        $year = get_post('year');
        $isbn =get_post('isbn');

        if (isset($_POST['delete']) && $isbn !='')
        {
            $query= "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='$isbn'";

            if (!mysql_query($query))
            {
                echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>". mysql_error() . "<p>";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" . "('$author','$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";
        if (!mysql_query($query))
        {
            echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" . mysql_error() . "<p>";
        }   
    }
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: ". mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j=0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
    $results[] = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

mysql_close($db_server);

$smarty->assign('results', $results);
$smarty->display("smartytest.tpl");

function get_post($var)
{
    return mysql_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

Also, here is the Smarty template file:

```
<html><head>
<title>Smarty Test</title>
</head><body>

<form action="/phptest/smartytest.php" method="post"><pre>
    Author <input type="text" name="author">
    Title<input type="text" name="title">
    Category<input type="text" name="category">
    Year<input type="text" name="year">
    ISBN<input type="text" name="isbn">
        <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
</pre></form>

{section name=row loop=$results}
    <form action="/phptest/smartytest.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
    <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="{$results[row].isbn}">
    <pre>
Author    {$results[row].author}
Title     {$results[row].title}
Category  {$results[row].category}
Year      {$results[row].year}
ISBN      {$results[row].isbn}
        <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD"></form>
    </pre>
{/section}

 </body></html>
```

My best guess is that there is something wrong with the nested if statements (which may be why not even the error message is displaying), but I've double checked the code and it looks good (at least to me). Does anyone notice anything wrong with this?  I can post a screen of what the page looks like if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the existence of `author, title, category, year, isbn` with `isset(..)` before checking to see what type of action was taken. There variables (like `$_POST['author']` are *not* set. Reason is that you have multiple forms on the page. Only the inputs that are within the form that is submitted are available in `$_POST`.

In this case, you could simply do:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])
    && isset($_POST['isbn'])
    && strlen($_POST['isbn'])) {
    // Remove record code here
}
else {
    // Add record code here
}
```